# Integrate a variable from within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having troubles getting the total hours needed depending on method of transport.

This is my first code as a lesson to familiarize myself with coding.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#calculateTotal').click(function () {


var a = ($('#car').val()) ? parseInt($('#car').val()) : 0;

var c = ($('#bus').val()) ? parseInt($('#bus').val()) : 0;


 document.getElementById("qr1").onclick = function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        var b = 1;
    }
    else {
        b = 0;
    }
};

var totalTime = a+b+c;

$('#total').html(totalTime);


});

});
```

var b is not being recognized as a variable when I click on Calculate Total. Can anyone show me the way as to how to declare var b in a way that makes sense in coding?

Thank you.

Comment: *1.* don't define a click handler within another click handler. *2.* you should add "var" before `b = 0;` *3.* b is only available within the callback for the `qr1` click handler you're defining, so won't be available outside that function. Solution: define it as a global variable or return it from a callback function, etc.

Comment: `b` is defined locally in scope. It does not exist globally.

Comment: You need to parseInt variable b. var totalTime = a+parseInt(b)+c

Comment: No, @scrowler, he should NOT add "var" before `b=0`.  He should REMOVE "var" before `b=1` to make `b` a global variable.  He uses `b` outside of the function.

Comment: @Godisgood I didn't suggest that it would make it global. It's just good practice.

Comment: It's not good practice, if he wants to re-use the variable later, @scrowler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring "b" inside of a function.

Because you want it to be globaly accessible outside of the function it was created in, remove the `var` from in front of it in the first statement.

```
document.getElementById("qr1").onclick = function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        b = 1;
    }
    else {
        b = 0;
    }
};
```

Alternatively you could set b outside of the function to 0

b = 0;

then

```
document.getElementById("qr1").onclick = function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        b = 1;
    }
};
```

As an aside, global s are usually frowned upon (I use them a lot) so you could create an object to house everything. This way you are nice and tidy.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, the qr1 click handler should be placed outside of the calculate total function.

Comment: Clear and concise. Thank you very much for your help.